# WordPress Php version update to 7.2

Tags: php, wordpress, version, godaddy-api

I could find only php 7.1 option in the GoDaddy is there any other way to update the php version to the latest version in GoDaddy ?

Answer (score 0):

If the providers php version is version 7.1 then you have no other option. You can not install it yourself. I will advice you to use virtual servers like https://digitalocean.com so to be flexible.

Answer (score 0):

From Godaddy: [Update PHP](https://www.godaddy.com/help/view-or-change-your-php-version-in-web-and-classic-hosting-3937) - note you cannot go back to php 5 if that becomes an issue